# JQuery AutoComplete action on Enter key

Tags: jquery

I want the AutoComplete to behave like this.

When the user is typing something in the textbox nothing should be happen..
  Autocomplete suggestion list should be appear only when the user has finished writing
  in the textbox and press the enter key..

Any idea how to do this.. Or where to change the code..

Comment: We need code to suggest on "where to change code"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***STEP : 1***

Change the **jquery.ui.autocomplete.js** file to accept the enter key by changing the method having signature as following

***.bind("keydown.autocomplete", function (event)***

and change it's following code

```
                case keyCode.ENTER:
                case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                    // when menu is open and has focus
                    if (self.menu.active) {
                        // #6055 - Opera still allows the keypress to occur
                        // which causes forms to submit
                        suppressKeyPress = true;
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    //passthrough - ENTER and TAB both select the current element
```

**To**

```
                case keyCode.ENTER:
                case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                    // when menu is open and has focus
                    if (self.menu.active) {
                        // #6055 - Opera still allows the keypress to occur
                        // which causes forms to submit
                        suppressKeyPress = true;
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    else {

                        clearTimeout(self.searching);
                        self.searching = setTimeout(function () {
                            // only search if the value has changed

                            self.selectedItem = null;
                            self.search(null, event);

                        }, self.options.delay);

                    }
                    //passthrough - ENTER and TAB both select the current element
```

***STEP : 2***
Changing autocomplete binding as

```
 $('.SearchAddresses').autocomplete({
  // Your bind code by setting required parameters

  search: function (event, ui) {
                var key = CheckBrowser(event);
                if (key == 13)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
   });


 function CheckBrowser(e) {
        if (window.event)
            key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
        else
            key = e.which;     //firefox
        return key;
    }
```

***SETP : 3***
If you are using it inside the asp.net form control

then include it as well.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("form").keypress(function (e) {
            var key = CheckBrowser(e);
            if (key == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to check keypress event for "Enter Key". When key pressed is "Enter", trigger  autocomplete function there as given below.

```
$(#inputBoxId).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
       $( "#elementId" ).autocomplete({
        //............... bind autocomplete and write your code
       });
    }
});
```

Try this.May be it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dynamically bind/unbind the control.  E.g. don't make it an autocomplete until the enter key is pressed?  Either readonly the source box, or remove if the text changes until they press enter again?  I'm pretty sure you can trigger the autocomplete event manually which would display the drop down.