# How To Get jQuery-UI Autocomplete To Trigger On Key Press

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm not quite sure if what I want is possible. But I currently have some code that populates an autocomplete list. The source is handled by an ajax call to a web api, that returns a set of items from the database (see code below).

```
$(".ItemSearch").on('keypress', function (event, ui) {
    var disabled = true;
    if (event.which === 13) {
        disabled = false;
    }
});

function BindItemNumberSearch(hostItemForm) {        
    if ($(".ItemSearch", hostItemForm).autocomplete({}).data("ui-autocomplete")) {
        $(".ItemSearch", hostItemForm).unbind("autocomplete");
        $(".ItemSearch", hostItemForm).autocomplete({
            close: function () {
                // some logic
            },
            response: function (event, ui) {
                // some logic if the item is empty
            },
            source: function (request, response) {
                // return if the search box is empty or is disabled
                if (request.term.trim().length <= 0 || disabled) {
                    return;
                }

                $.ajax({ 
                    // some ajax call
                });
            },
            delay: 500,
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                // return false if no item is selected
                if (ui.item.id != null) {
                    return false;
                }

                // some logic to select the item
            }
        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = RenderSearchResultItem;
    }           
}
```

The issue we are having is that sometimes the request to search can be sent before the user has finished typing out the search string. This used to be OK as the search would return quickly, but now we have too much data and it is causing slowness (we think due to multiple searches being kicked off as the user slowly types what they are looking for).

So we would like to add a trigger on key press (such as the enter key) to kick off the search. I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416727/jquery-autocomplete-action-on-enter-key), and it seems jQuery-ui does not support this. I've tried different attempts, the one included is the latest. However I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: "but now we have too much data and it is causing slowness (we think due to multiple searches being kicked off as the user slowly types what they are looking for)." This might not be the "right" answer your looking for, but you could always limit the user to a minimal number of characters needed to begin the search (https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength) . Alternatively you could make a call cue function that sends and waits for data one after another decreasing performance impact but loosing search speed.

Comment: IMO calling an ajax function on every keypress might not be the best approach. I would suggest that for every additional keypress try to filter the result from previous list as adding a new character to an existing string would not bring any new results. To address user entering totally new item, you can store the "search string" (what you are searching for) in a global variable, and before every search check if the previous "search string" is in the new "search string", and if true, search inside previous result, if not, then submit ajax.

Comment: @AlwaysaLearner I don't want the function to run on every keypress, it does that already. I want it to run after a specific key is pressed (like enter). I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: is the on('keypress') being triggered? What do you expect to happen when you set disabled = false ? It has been declared in local scope so its not going to have an effect outside the function.

Comment: have you considered `debouncing` or `throttling` the ajax request? it could simulate the old behaviour of your autocomplete, while likely taking off a large load from your remote server.

Comment: @Bryn that was a typo the variable is declared at the global scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign a flag for when your `autocomplete` should start searching.

```
// this will be the flag if autocomplete should begin searching
// should become true when [Enter] key is pressed & input field is not empty
window.BeginSearch = false;
```

After that, attach a DOM Event to your `autocomplete` element that would detect the `Enter` key

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#tags", function(e) {
    ...
})
```

Programatically instruct the `autocomplete` to start searching as needed when the `Enter` key is pressed

```
$("#tags").autocomplete("search");
```

Inside the `source` callback, this is when the flag variable will come in handy. Use this to detect if `Enter` key was pressed and therefore have set `BeginSearch` to `true`

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        if (window.BeginSearch != true || request.term.trim().length <= 0) {
            response([]);
            window.BeginSearch = false; // reset the flag since searching is finished
            return;
        } else if (window.BeginSearch == true) {
            sample_async_function(request).then(function (return_data) {
                response(return_data);
                window.BeginSearch = false; // reset the flag since searching is finished
            });
        }
    },
    delay: 0 // no need for delay, as you can see
});
```

---

### Sample Demo:

```js
// this event will be responsible for tracking [Enter] key press
$(document).on("keydown", "#tags", function(e) {

  // additional checks so that autocomplete search won't occur if conditions are not met
  if (e.key == "Enter" && $("#tags").val().trim().length > 0 && $(".sample-loader:visible").length < 1) {
    window.BeginSearch = true;
    $("#tags").autocomplete("search");
  }
})

$(document).ready(function() {

  // this will be the flag if autocomplete should begin searching
  // should become true when [Enter] key is pressed & input field is not empty
  window.BeginSearch = false;

  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      if (window.BeginSearch != true || request.term.trim().length <= 0) {
        response([]);
        window.BeginSearch = false; // reset the flag since searching is finished
        return;
      } else if (window.BeginSearch == true) {
        sample_async_function(request).then(function(return_data) {
          response(return_data);
          window.BeginSearch = false; // reset the flag since searching is finished
        });
      }
    },
    delay: 0 // no need for delay, as you can see
  });

});

// sample asynchronous function. mimics fetching data from server side (e.g., ajax) 
function sample_async_function(some_passed_string) {
  $(".sample-loader").show();
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    $(".sample-loader").hide();
    resolve(
      [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
      ].filter((val, index) => {
        if (val.toLowerCase().includes(some_passed_string.term.toLowerCase())) {
          return val;
        }
      })
    );
  }, 500)); // arbitrary value. sample speed of the API XHR in unit milliseconds
}
```

```css
.sample-loader {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1053;
  background: #000000dd;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">AutoComplete: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>

<div class="sample-loader">Loading...</div>
```

From a UX perspective, you are going to want to figure out how to temporarily disable interactions with the element when the searching is in progress. In this example, I have used a simple "loading" screen.

Comment: I had done this, but it looks like what I was missing was manually triggering the search. This seems to get the behavior i desire.